# I don't understand what the multiplication in q.offer(x*m + y) does and what the while loop is doing and everything in the code

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, iteration

Can someone explain this code in detail, I don't understand what the multiplication in q.offer(x*m + y) does and what the while loop is doing. This is the requirements for the program:

Starting from a given location on the grid, experiment explores the grid, expanding and labeling all of the cells in a single colony originating from the starting location. Taking as input a grid, the coordinates of a starting location, and a label, experiment will either label that location and all its neighbors or do nothing, depending on the presence or absence of a cell at the given location, respectively; either way, experiment is required to return the size of the labeled colony.
(c) The program is responsible for ensuring that experiment is called start- ing at every location on the grid storing a 1. The reason is that experiment locates only a single colony.
For example, using the first grid above and calling experiment for the first time on the location at the top row and forth column will modify the grid only at the locations labeled A, leaving all the other locations intact.
Once every grid location storing a 1 has been colonized, the program freezes the grid by replacing the 0s on the grid with s (dashes) .
(d) The program is responsible for creating an initial grid of random number of rows and columns in the range [5-20], and for filling the grid randomly with 0s and 1s.
(e) The program is responsible for generating the labels for experiment to use during exploration. Use the alphabet letters A · · · Z and a · · · z as labels (in that order).

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> experiment(int n, int m, int x, int y, char[][] matrix, int[][] mark, char colony) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    q.offer(x*m + y);
    mark[x][y] = 1;
    matrix[x][y] = colony;

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        int front = q.peek();   q.remove();
        int x1 = front / m, y1 = front % m;
        if(x1 != 0)
            if(mark[x1-1][y1] == 0 && matrix[x1-1][y1] == '1') {
                matrix[x1-1][y1] = colony;
                mark[x1-1][y1] = 1;
                q.offer((x1-1) * m + y1);
            }
```

I just don't understand this part of code. Can someone please explain it.

Comment: Without knowing what all the arguments to the function mean, it's unlikely anybody can help.

Answer (score 0):

one possible explanation could be that
x and y are coordinates of grid,
if you loop over x and y as below

```
for( int x = 0 ; x < width; x++ ){
    for( int y = 0 ; y < height; y++ ){
         index_of_one_dimensional_array = x*m+y;//where m = width(i.e number if columns in each row) 
    }
}
```

seems like the q.offer() functions somehow uses this concept to set a value depending on value of index_of_one_dimensional_array given by x*m+y;

and loop is used to make sure every cell in the grid is processed which happens when the queue is empty